# Can A C Compiler Eliminate This Conditional Test At Runtime?

Tags: c, optimization, configuration

Let's say I have pseudocode like this:

```
main() {
    BOOL b = get_bool_from_environment(); //get it from a file, network, registry, whatever
    while(true) {
        do_stuff(b);
    }
}

do_stuff(BOOL b) {
    if(b)
        path_a();
    else
        path_b();
}
```

Now, since we know that the external environment can influence `get_bool_from_environment()` to *potentially* produce either a true or false result, then we know that the code for both the true and false branches of `if(b)` must be included in the binary. We can't simply omit `path_a();` or `path_b();` from the code.

BUT -- we only set `BOOL b` the one time, and we always reuse the same value after program initialization.

If I were to make this valid C code and then compile it using `gcc -O0`, the `if(b)` would be repeatedly evaluated on the processor each time that `do_stuff(b)` is invoked, which inserts what are, in my opinion, needless instructions into the pipeline for a branch that is basically static after initialization.

If I were to assume that I actually had a compiler that was as stupid as `gcc -O0`, I would re-write this code to include a function pointer, and two separate functions, `do_stuff_a()` and `do_stuff_b()`, which don't perform the `if(b)` test, but simply go ahead and perform one of the two paths. Then, in `main()`, I would assign the function pointer based on the value of `b`, and call that function in the loop. This eliminates the branch, though it admittedly adds a memory access for the function pointer dereference (due to architecture implementation I [don't think](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2438539/does-function-pointer-make-the-program-slow) I really need to worry about that).

Is it possible, even in principle, for a compiler to take code of the same style as the original pseudocode sample, and to realize that the test is unnecessary once the value of `b` is assigned once in `main()`? If so, what is the theoretical name for this compiler optimization, and can you please give an example of an actual compiler implementation (open source or otherwise) which does this?

I realize that compilers can't generate dynamic code at runtime, and the only types of systems that could do that in principle would be bytecode virtual machines or interpreters (e.g. Java, .NET, Ruby, etc.) -- so the question remains whether or not it is possible to do this **statically** and generate code that contains both the `path_a();` branch and the `path_b()` branch, but avoid evaluating the *conditional test* `if(b)` for every call of `do_stuff(b);`.

Comment: C compilers don't know anything about your program at run-time.

Comment: Is this a bottleneck in your code? Programming assuming compiler optimizations is brittle.

Comment: @dmckee it will have to contain `path_b();` because the compiler can't determine ahead of time what the input from the environment will cause the value of `b` to be assigned to. For instance, if reading from a file, you could modify the file in some way that would change the value of `b` from true to false. The code would have to work in both cases, calling the appropriate `path_a()` or `path_b()` function. But the value of `b` doesn't change after the loop begins, so you can actually write a valid C program that uses function pointers to "statically" call one path, eliminating the test.

Comment: You're wondering whether it can hoist the `if (b)` outside the `while` loop.  It can.  I don't know of any current compiler that will.

Comment: I just wanted to avoid having to use the function pointers for readability/maintainability purposes (because they're messy) if possible, and use the "lazy" type of pseudocode I wrote above instead, if this type of optimization is common. But it sounds like I will have to use function pointers to avoid the branch in the tight loop.

Comment: Thanks @tmyklebu, that helps. Your analysis is correct. The topic of whether compilers actually *do* it is also interesting, but I was more interested in the theory of what exactly a static compiler could do with this without conceding any sort of runtime code modification.

Comment: Yes, a compiler can theoretically optimize the code by employing three optimizations: Inlining, hosting, and unrolling.

Comment: Some of you have posted comments that would be the start of a good answer, or a good answer in and of themselves. If anyone who feels they have a good handle on this wants to post an answer, I am ready to accept. This discussion has certainly been helpful.

Comment: Perhaps you should change the title from "can" to "does"...

Comment: @Oli only problem with that is there is no universal agreement on what "a <generic> C compiler does" -- even if you assume full standards compliance, optimization is another matter entirely... sometimes optimizations even violate the specs (!), but even when they don't, they're undefined behavior as far as the language specs are concerned. So I'd have to make a question about my specific compiler/environment. I was going for the theory more than anything though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you tell your compiler to optimise, you have a good chance that the `if(b)` is evaluated only once.

Slightly modifying the given example, using the standard `_Bool` instead of `BOOL`, and adding the missing return types and declarations,

```
_Bool get_bool_from_environment(void);
void path_a(void);
void path_b(void);

void do_stuff(_Bool b) {
    if(b)
        path_a();
    else
        path_b();
}

int main(void) {
    _Bool b = get_bool_from_environment(); //get it from a file, network, registry, whatever
    while(1) {
        do_stuff(b);
    }
}
```

the (relevant part of the) produced assembly by `clang -O3` [clang-3.0] is

```
    callq   get_bool_from_environment
    cmpb    $1, %al
    jne     .LBB1_2
    .align  16, 0x90
.LBB1_1:                                # %do_stuff.exit.backedge.us
                                        # =>This Inner Loop Header: Depth=1
    callq   path_a
    jmp     .LBB1_1
    .align  16, 0x90
.LBB1_2:                                # %do_stuff.exit.backedge
                                        # =>This Inner Loop Header: Depth=1
    callq   path_b
    jmp     .LBB1_2
```

`b` is tested only once, and `main` jumps into an infinite loop of either `path_a` or `path_b` depending on the value of `b`. If `path_a` and `path_b` are small enough, they would be inlined (I strongly expect). With `-O` and `-O2`, the code produced by clang would evaluate `b` in each iteration of the loop.

gcc (4.6.2) behaves similarly with `-O3`:

```
    call    get_bool_from_environment
    testb   %al, %al
    jne     .L8
    .p2align 4,,10
    .p2align 3
.L9:
    call    path_b
    .p2align 4,,6
    jmp     .L9
.L8:
    .p2align 4,,8
    call    path_a
    .p2align 4,,8
    call    path_a
    .p2align 4,,5
    jmp     .L8
```

oddly, it unrolled the loop for `path_a`, but not for `path_b`. With `-O2` or `-O`, it would however call `do_stuff` in the infinite loop.

Hence to

> Is it possible, even in principle, for a compiler to take code of the same style as the original pseudocode sample, and to realize that the test is unnecessary once the value of `b` is assigned once in `main()`?

the answer is a definitive Yes, it is possible for compilers to recognize this and take advantage of that fact. Good compilers do when asked to optimise hard.

> If so, what is the theoretical name for this compiler optimization, and can you please give an example of an actual compiler implementation (open source or otherwise) which does this?

I don't know the name of the optimisation, but two implementations doing that are gcc and clang (at least, recent enough releases).

Comment: VERY interesting that you have to give `clang` the `-O3` switch to get it to do this and that `-O2` is not enough! I've seen lots and lots of code (both in my own work and others') in similar situations, so I wonder how many times we pass a conservative `-O2` to a build script and introduce tons of needless branching in a tight loop. Anyway, this is great, as I actually do use gcc-4.6 and, less frequently, clang, in my work. Thanks!!!

Comment: I was surprised that `-O2` wasn't enough too. Of course, if the testing of `b` mattered in terms of execution speed, any branch predictor would make it almost free, so one would not lose very much. If you make `do_stuff` a `static inline` function, gcc does something weird with `-O2`; the `true` path would test in each iteration, the `false` part only once at the beginning.