# Link Multiple Declarations to Same Definition

Tags: c

I have implemented a linked list in C (not C++) that stores pointers to data.  I would like to have multiple declarations for its functions (to provide type safety), but have each of them link to the same definition (because there is no actual difference between pointers to different data types, so using the same code reduces space).

Does anyone have any ideas on how to achieve this (or any better ways to do it)?  A portable solution is obviously best, but I really just need something that works in GCC.

Comment: Does writing multiple declarations really give you any type safety? I'm assuming you'd have insert/remove functions that are overloaded - what prevents you from inserting with one type, and removing with another?

Comment: @derekerdmann: One of the declarations would take an int* (for instance), so the compiler would complain if you tried to pass that declaration a myStruct*.  The definition would take a void*.  The compiler would see each declaration as a separate function, and they only become the same when the linker gets to them.

Comment: The declaration also needs to take a `void*` for the `myStruct*` to be accepted - that's what the compiler looks at when it's figuring out if the arguments match, not the definition.

Comment: @derekerdmann:  Sorry; I was not clear enough.  There would be multiple declarations of the form add_int(int*), add_myStruct(myStruct*), etc.  That way, the compiler would not allow giving add_int a myStruct, like you said.  That is where the type safety comes from.  Then, at the linking stage, all of the declarations get linked to the generic add(void*) to eliminate redundancy.

Comment: Except it's not really giving you type safety. The linked list operates on `void*`, so there's nothing preventing you from calling `add_int` to insert a value, and `get_myStruct` to remove the exact same value. It's not actually making your operations safer, and it's up to you to keep track of which types are stored in which lists.

Comment: You might be better off just using `void*` data types and casting it yourself when you pull the data out - see https://gist.github.com/derekerdmann/5632392

Comment: @derekerdmann This is c; that kind of responsibility comes with the turf. I agree with you about the risks of what the OP is trying to achieve. On the other hand, it would make the calling code much clearer in its intentions: `add_int(&i)` is a small improvement over `add(&i)`.

Comment: Also, having multiple declarations all pointing to one definition allows you to change the definition of one in the future. If, say, `add_myStruct` had to do something special; you could easily redefine the function without breaking an calling code. Because everything would be calling `add_myStruct` instead of just `add`.

Comment: @derekerdmann:  Sorry; my miscommunication again.  `add_int` would also take an `int_list` (and `get_myStruct` a `myStruct_list`), which is what would prevent you from using the function for the wrong type (well, unless you cast pointers, but then you know that you are messing with things).

Comment: @LonelyIsland So it's the same idea as Java's generics: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generics_in_Java#Problems_with_type_erasure

Comment: @derekerdmann:  Yes.  If I knew that much Java, that is exactly how I would have explained it.  Thanks for repeatedly pointing out my inability to communicate :).

Comment: Hmm, do you want the same function, or multiple copies of the same function, each handling a different type? There's a difference, particularly if the types are incompatible. If you want to implement the function once, and have multiple type safe versions, the solution I'm used to involves token pasting and the C preprocessor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you might be able to achieve this using typedefs for function prototypes and
casting the generic solution (which deals in `void*`s) to the specific prototype. This should be safe for compilation because all pointers would be the same size.

Consider this example:

`do_something.h`:

```
typedef void (*do_something_with_int_t)(int *i);
extern do_something_with_int_t do_something_with_int;

typedef void (*do_something_with_string_t)(char *s);
extern do_something_with_string_t do_something_with_string;
```

`do_something.c`

```
#include "do_something.h"

void do_something_generic(void* p) {
    // Do something generic with p
}


do_something_with_int_t do_something_with_int =
    (do_something_with_int_t)do_something_generic;

do_something_with_string_t do_something_with_string =
    (do_something_with_string_t)do_something_generic;
```

As long as `do_something_generic` is truly datatype-agnostic (i.e. it *really* doesn't matter what `p` points to) then this would be OK.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
struct common_type {
    int type;
};

struct type1 {
    int type;
    int value;
};

struct type2 {
    int type;
    char* p;
};

int func(void *para) {
    switch (((struct common_type*)para)->type) {
        case 1:
            printf("type1,value:%d\n",((struct type1*)para)->value);
            break;
        case 2:
            printf("type2,content:%s\n",((struct type2*)para)->p);
            break;
    }
}

int main() {
    char *s = "word";
    struct type1 t1 = {1,1};
    struct type2 t2;
    t2.type = 2;
    t2.p = s;
    func((void*)&t1);   
    func((void*)&t2);
}
```

Comment: Did you even read the question?  Your answer addresses the common problem of multiple definition, which is NOT what my question is about.  My question is about practically the opposite, using one definition for multiple declarations.  I appreciate that you put in the effort to help, but I would appreciate it more if you put that effort towards the right question.

Comment: In this case,put the defintion in a header file,and declarations in files which use the struct. I have write some code addational,did you mean that?

Comment: No; that still addresses the wrong question.  I am looking for a way to have multiple declarations all get linked to the same "generic" function.

Comment: @LonelyIsland Okay, I've updated a piece of new code, the older ones have been deleted.

Answer (score 0):

If it's C (not C++), then the following will work just fine. You can adapt the concept to your needs.

**tt.h**

```
typedef struct {
    int ii;
} Type_1;

typedef struct {
    int ii;
} Type_2;

int foo_1(Type_1* ptr) __attribute__((alias("foo")));
int foo_2(Type_2* ptr) __attribute__((alias("foo")));
```

**tt.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>

#include "tt.h"

int main() {
    Type_1 t_1;
    Type_2 t_2;
    foo_1(&t_1);
    foo_2(&t_2);
}   

int foo(void* arg) {
    printf("foo: %p\n", arg);
}
```

Comment: @anthony-arnold:  I do not really care about portability, so I am going to use Ziffusion's answer in my code (for efficiency; I believe your answer takes an extra instruction or two per call).  However, I am accepting your answer because it is the more general answer for someone who might come across this question later.  Thank you to both of you!

Comment: @LonelyIsland See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2438539/does-function-pointer-make-the-program-slow) for an examplanation re efficiency. A good compiler will generate virtually the same machine code.

Comment: @anthony-arnold:  I had figured that GCC would optimize it away, but I was thinking about the non-optimized cases... I do not know why.  Anyway, good point, and I suppose I will be using your way after all.

Comment: @LonelyIsland The non-optimized case can be drastically different depending on your compiler. MSVC wraps the function-pointer call in a function which sanity-checks the stack. But that's for a debug build, and you have to accept the sacrifice in order to develop your code properly. For a release, you would turn on optimisations.