# c++: Overhead using a function via function ptr

Tags: c++, overhead

Is there a (even a small) overhead calling a function via function-ptr instead of calling it directly?

Comment: It seems very likely that there is, but since the answer must depend on what compiler you are using you should write some code and see what machine code your compiler generates.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2438539/does-function-pointer-make-the-program-slow

Comment: function-ptr  is very less likely to be inlined (because the compiler cannot easily assume a *particular* function to be inlined), but there are chances for function/functor to be inlined.